# Cucumber/Capybara - Using RSpec matchers with a "Page Object" pattern

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm currently refactoring a whole load of cucumber tests to use a "Page Object" pattern, but I'm having a lot of problems using the RSpec matchers.

The existing step I have is as follows:

```
Then /^I should (not )?see the following alerts:$/ do |negate, alerts|
  expectation = negate ? :should_not : :should

  within(ALERT_TABLE_ID) do
    alerts.hashes.each do |alert|
      page.send(expectation, have_content(alert["Original ID"]))
    end
  end
end
```

My refactored step is:

```
Then /^I should (not )?see the following alerts:$/ do |negate, alerts|
  expectation = negate ? :should_not : :should

  @alert_reporting_panel = AlertReportingPanel.new(Capybara.current_session)
  @alert_reporting_panel.verify_contents expectation, alerts
end
```

And my Panel Object is:

```
class AlertReportingPanel
  def initialize(session)
    @session = session
  end

  def verify_contents(expectation, alerts)
    @session.within(ALERT_TABLE_ID) do
      alerts.hashes.each do |alert|
        @session.send(expectation, have_content(alert["Original ID"]))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, I get `undefined method 'have_contents' for #<AlertReportingPanel:0x3f0faf8> (NoMethodError)`.
I have tried adding `require 'rspec'` to the top of the class and also tried fully qualifying the `have-content` method thus:  `Capybara::RSpecMatchers::HaveMatcher.have_content`,  but I just get `uninitialized constant Capybara::RSpecMatchers (NameError)`.

I'm pretty new to Ruby and I'm sure this is trivial to fix... but I just can't seem to work it out for myself.

Please help.   Thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a while back so I'm guessing you may have your answer by now but here goes.

You need to include the necessary modules in order bring in and have access to the likes of *have_content*. So your Panel Object would look like:

```
class AlertReportingPanel
    include Capybara::DSL
    include Capybara::Node::Matchers
    include RSpec::Matchers

    def initialize... etc
```

Comment: Thankyou for this.   Sorry about the delay, I was busy on another project that didn't use ruby/cucumber.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing your own Page Object system you could try using [SitePrism](https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism)

I'm a little biased (I wrote that gem) but it might make life easier for you.